# how to sign saml 2.0 authnrequest in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, saml, saml-2.0

I am the Service provider using native c# code to generate saml 2.0 AuthnRequest and consuming the SamlResponse. The client has asked us to sign the saml AuthnRequest and then send it to them. We are sending it as http-POST. 
Here's the data we have:

1. The metadata of idp containing their x509 certificate.
2. Our own x509 certificate along with our private key. Used this tool to get a self signed one https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php
3. Our own SP Metadata (entity descriptor) Signed using the self-signed certificate and private key, using this tool https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php

Now, with the above information, how do i sign my AuthnRequest ?

Comment: I also have same requirements. Pls share the solution.

Comment: Hi, anyone have solved this?